# upload image without losing quality in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to upload some images and crop that without losing their quality in ruby on rails.For uploading images i have seen gems like paperclip,refile and CarrierWave.Which one will be better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Choosing between CarrierWave, Paperclip and Refile can be difficult at
>   times, but I would always recommend CarrierWave. It is the most
>   powerful and customizable of the three. It keeps your code organized
>   and clean, and is easy to test.
>
> Refile isn't ready for prime time yet as it is still experiencing
>   growth pains and has DoS issues, and Paperclip is fairly simplistic.

[image]

For more information please see this acrticle: [Best Rails image uploader - Paperclip vs. Carrierwave vs. Refile](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/best-rails-image-uploader-paperclip-carrierwave-refile)